# Attribute with dynamic objects

Tags: c#

I have the following attribute definition:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
      public TestAttribute(List<string> values)
      {
      }
}
```

The following use of the attribute produces an error:

```
[Test(new List<string>() { "123", "456" }]
class A
{
}
```

The error is:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

Any help please? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 .NET 4.5.

I don't want to use `params string[]` instead of `List<string>`.

Comment: I'm sorry i just edited the question guys, can you have a look at it now.

Comment: yep - now it makes sense!

Comment: `I don't want to use params string[] instead of List<string>.`: unfortunately that's not going to matter. The CLR isn't going to allow anything else.

Comment: Why don't you wanna use `params`? Whats wrong with that? seems perfect

Comment: I want to pass objects of specific types not something static.

Comment: If you need to use it somewhere else or something (but why?) just overload it…

Comment: If you want to, just convert the string array to a list inside the attribute constructor, and then expose it as a property such as `public List<string> MyProperty {get; private set; }`

Comment: So you're telling me that C# does not ever support using NEW in the attribute constructor.

Comment: @hiddenUser, `I want to pass objects of specific types not something static.`: that pretty much goes against the definition of an `Attribute` then. Attributes only receive static values by nature. Take a look at the first part of the error message - `must be a constant expression`.

Comment: @hiddenUser, that's 100% correct, they do not support `new` inside of an attribute.

Comment: You can use it _inside_ the constructor, just not as an argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message told you, you supply that as an argument to an attribute constructor. Generally anything you have to create with `new` is not valid as that is not constant but allocated at run time.

As the error message suggests, you could just use an array instead. In your case, it’s very simple to do with a params array:

```
public TestAttribute(params string[] values)
{ }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
[Test("123", "456")]
class A
{ }
```

Note though, that you have defined `TestAttribute` to be only valid for methods, not for class declarations. So this will still fail.

---

> I don't want to use `params string[]` instead of `List<string>`.

Well, you don’t have much of a choice, you could use a plain array, so you would have to write `new string[] {"123", "456"}` instead—that doesn’t give you any benefit though.

If you really want a list, although there really shouldn’t be a need for it, you can create it in the constructor:

```
public TestAttribute(params string[] values)
{
    List<string> valuesList = new List<string>(values);
}
```

---

> I want to pass objects of specific types not something static.

You cannot ever pass anything dynamic to attributes. They are evaluated quite early when the declaration is processed, so at that time it’s unlikely that the rest of your code was executed.

Comment: Thanks lot you does gave it all!

Answer (score 5):

Just like the message sais, it's simply not supported in c#. (The reason is that attributes are metadata and it should be possible to reflect/read metadata without executing code - such as initializing a list).

But you can use the params keyword:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
    public TestAttribute(params string[] values)
    {
    }
}

[Test("123", "456")]
class A
{
}
```